# Python syntax error on calling function for bubble_sort script

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am running a bubble_sort script obtained from a git repo here https://github.com/engineer-man/youtube/blob/master/009/bubble.py, but I get a syntax error when running the following code;

```
def sort(arr):
    while True:
        corrected = False
        for i in range(0, len(arr) - 1):
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
                corrected = True
        if not corrected:
            return arr

# best O(n)
print sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
# average O(n^2)
print sort([4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 5])
# worst O(n^2)
print sort([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

... results in

```
  File "test.py", line 13
    print sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any pointers, please?

Comment: Looks like you are using python3X...`Use print(sort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use python3

```
print(sort([...]))
```

You need to add parenthesis.

Comment: Ahhh drat... sorry, yes indeed.  Python 3.  Thank you.